# how to solve steps skip the last frame while set animate for infinite?

Tags: css, frontend

I want to realize type letters effect use CSS 3 property "animation".
But I found when I set animation infinite , steps(1, end) always skip the last key frame. I want to add the animation in which i will skip the last frame while set the animation for the infinite.
Kindly help me to animate the text.

```css
/*type keyframes*/
@keyframes type {
    from {
        left: 0%; 
    }

    to {
        left: 100%; 
    }
}
/*cursor flash keyframes*/
@keyframes flash {
    from {
        color: rgb(255,255,255);
    }

    50% {
        color: rgb(102,102,102);
    }

    to {
        color: rgb(255,255,255);
    }
}

body {
    background: #666; 
}

.text { 
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; 
    left: 50%;
    top: 100px;
    cursor: text;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
    position: relative;
    font-family: monospace;
}

/*mask layer*/
.text::before {
    content: "|"; 
    font-weight: lighter;
    text-align: left;
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #666;
    animation: type 1s steps(12, end) infinite, flash 1s steps(1, end) infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">hello world!</div>
```

I had try add `animation-fill-mode: forwards`, but it did'n work also.
Is there exist an easy way to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an extra step and increase the `left` value in the keyframes by a character.

```css
@keyframes type {
  to {
    left: calc(100% + 1ch);
  }
}

@keyframes flash {
  from {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  }

  50% {
    color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
  }

  to {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  }
}

body {
  background: grey;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  left: 50%;
  top: 100px;
  cursor: text;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.text::before {
  content: "|";
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-align: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #666;
  animation: type 1s steps(13, end) infinite, flash 1s steps(13, end) infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">hello world!</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, forgive me it takes a long time to feedback